Auto delete completed orders older than 3 months in Woocommerce with HPOS
I need to set up WooCommerce to automatically clean up completed orders older than 3 months and found How to automatically delete old completed orders in Woocommerce answer code, which does not work with High Performance Orders Storage (HPOS) activated.
Here is my code attempt:
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'auto_trash_old_completed_orders_345erhwe546' );
function auto_trash_old_completed_orders_345erhwe546() {
    global $nm_theme_options;

    if ( isset( $nm_theme_options['delete_all_woo_orders_older_then_3_months'] ) && $nm_theme_options['delete_all_woo_orders_older_then_3_months'] == 1 ) {
        // Theme option is set to delete old orders

        $completed_order_ids = wc_get_orders( array(
            'limit'         => 100, // By batch of 100 orders
            'status'        => 'completed', 
            'return'        => 'ids',
            'date_created'  => '<' . date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '-3 months' ) ),
        ) );

        if ( count( $completed_order_ids ) > 0 ) {
            // Orders found, proceed to delete

            foreach ( $completed_order_ids as $completed_order_id ) {
                $trashed = wp_trash_post( $completed_order_id );
                $deleted = wp_delete_post( $completed_order_id, true );

                // DEBUG
                if ( ! $trashed || ! $deleted ) {
                    echo '<script>alert("Error deleting order ID: ' . $completed_order_id . '");</script>';
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        // DEBUG
        echo '<script>alert("Orders deleted: ' . count( $completed_order_ids ) . '");</script>';
        
    } else {
        
        // DEBUG
        echo '<script>alert("Theme option not set to delete old orders.");</script>';
        
    }
}

I added some debug statements and getting "Error deleting order ID" for each Order ID. Any idea how to fix it?

When High Performance Orders Storage (HPOS) is enabled, classic WordPress post and post meta functions should not be used. Instead, you can use WC_Data delete() method, like:
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'auto_trash_old_completed_orders' );
function auto_trash_old_completed_orders(){
    $completed_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'         => 100, // By batch of 100 orders
        'status'        => 'completed', 
        'date_created'  => '<' . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-6 months")),
    ) );

    if ( count($completed_orders) > 0 ){
        foreach( $completed_orders as $completed_order ) {
            $completed_order->delete(true); 
        }
    }
} 

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.
Note that I have reduced the number of orders to be processed… This "limit" argument should be fine tuned depending on the hosting.

thx - so no trash needed anymore before deleting?

No more trash needed…
